# how to make the first label looks the same height as other labels in vertical stackview? why the first label become "shorter" than other labels

Tags: autolayout

[image: this is my view hierarchy]
[image: constraint of the stack view]

[image: constraint of the stack view]
[image: constraint of the stack view]

How to make the first label looks the same height as other labels in vertical stackview?
Why the first label become "shorter" than other labels?